# Candidates whose nominations have been withdrawn are still visible in the dropdown on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, responsive-design

When a candidate's nomination is withdrawn, their username is removed from the menu that lists candidates to be added to the ballot (on desktop). However, on mobile (responsive mode), the dropdown still shows the users whose nominations have been withdrawn.

On the following side by side screenshots of the [current Stack Overflow election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13), only 5 candidates are listed on the menu on desktop, while 6 are listed in the dropdown on mobile:

[image: Side by side view of the selectable candidates on desktop vs on mobile]

<sup>(Username(s) were anonymized to not make it about certain users)</sup>

Note: selecting the candidate's username from the dropdown does not actually add it to the ballot, but it still should be removed for consistency with the desktop view.

Comment: Related post on Meta.SO: [Candidate count has not been updated since one candidate was withdrawn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412483/8967612)

Comment: This has been added to our backlog to be addressed as part of regular bug duty rotation. We'll let you know when we have updates.

Comment: @JNat "bug duty rotation" sounds nice, any bonus based on amount of bugs fixed? ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is fixed. Withdrawn candidates will no longer show up in the mobile voting controls

> withdrawn candidate
> now hidden in the dropdown
> on narrow screen width